# Cannot find KRE package kre-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3, Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6

Tags: asp.net-core, dnx, kre

I installed Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6, I create a ASP.NET MVC 6 project and i receive following error at build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Cannot find KRE package kre-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3 in the folder: C:\Users\cornel.adavidoaiei\.k\runtimes
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AspNet\Microsoft.Web.AspNet.targets(111,5): error : The ProjectK Runtime package needs to be installed. See output window for more details.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am looking in "C:\Users\cornel.adavidoaiei.k\runtimes\kre-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3" and it isn't any bin here but i have bin in "C:\Users\cornel.adavidoaiei.k\runtimes\kre-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta3", why doesn't use x64 version which is installed and try to use x86 version of kre which is missing, any idea how could to solve this issue ?

Comment: If you're using beta3, I don't believe you're using dnx - I suggest you remove the dnx tag. What does kvm upgrade do for you?

Comment: try kvm upgrade, 
then kvm list (to confirm the latest release is installed)